# apt-get upgrade, stops grub booting usb

Tags: usb, grub2

I am attempting to setup a htpc, with ubuntu booting from USB and 3 SATA disks as a raid array.

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 minimal to the USB device, everything was working OK for the first few hours, however after running apt-get upgrade, it no longer boots from GRUB2 (the usual blinking cursor issue)
However, it boots fine if I disconnect the sata HDD in the machine (so the USB device is the only boot device)

I am assuming (correct me if I am wrong) that the SATA disk is being assigned /dev/sda and attempting to boot from HDD, and therefore the USB device is getting the wrong /dev/sdX?

other notes, the sata disks are unpartitioned and pressing shift during boot does not bring up the grub menu also.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your BIOS settings, bring Boot from USB to top.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for the late reply folks. I've since found out that it is a fault with either my machine(motherboard) or the usb device I was using. I attempted this on a different PC while I was at work with a different thumb drive and it had no issues.

For reference my motherboard is a MSI H67MAE35 and the USB device was a PNY 4GB thumb drive.